# Matlab R14SP3 - receiving UDP packet

Tags: java, matlab, sockets, udp

Unfortunately I'm using pretty old Matlab version (R14SP3 from 2005). I'd like to read some UDP packets and analyse them.
As this version of Matlab doesn't contains a package to handle the IP, but it contains Java, I'm trying to use Java to receive the data.

I see that there is socket opening (with netstat/tcpview), I see in wireshark that there is a traffic, but I don't receive it:

```
socket = DatagramSocket(1900);
socket.setSoTimeout(10e3);
socket.setReuseAddress(1);
packet = DatagramPacket(zeros(1,packetLength,'int8'),packetLength);        
socket.receive(packet); %<=here I'm waiting 10 seconds while there is active traffic on udp port 1900
```

Comment: Which version of MATLAB is the "pretty old version"

Comment: @Wolfie - R14SP3